# How to process data to be displayed faster when using ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, ngfor

I have a JSON with 3500 data. I want to show there in view, but data show very slowly and application work very slowly.

I have this JSON:

```
    export class Service {
        private items = new Array<Mjeket>(
            { "Emer": "Iliriana"},
            { "Emer": "Ada" },
            { "Emer": "Ada"},
            { "Emer": "Adela"},......{...})

   getallitems(): Array<Items> {
        return this.items;
    }
    }
```

In component.ts I have:

```
getall() {
    this.items = this.service.getallitems();
}
```

In component.html

```
 <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
             <GridLayout columns="*,*,*" rows="auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                                <Label [text]="item.Emer" class="list-group-item-heading"
                                    style="width: 60%; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; color: black;"
                                    row="0" col='0' horizontalAlignment="left"></Label>                 
                         </GridLayout>
                </StackLayout>
```

How to make that data show fast, not very slowly when I have more data. Any idea please?

Comment: If you have a long list, try to stick with ListView / RadListView. ngFor is not recommended for such use case.

Comment: Like @Manoj say, ngFor its a bad choice in this case, check this [link](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/ng-RadListView/load-on-demand) RadListView have LoadOnDemand functionality for this cases

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't render all your data at once. You render it on demand by scrolling.

One of the options (ready solutions) is you can use virtual scroller. Possible options are:

- https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#scrolling-strategies
- https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller

I think you can find more, it is just two which I worked with.

It is not problem of Angular itself. It is how browsers and DOM works. So in case of big data, you have to handle this somehow (virtual scrolling, pagination, live scrolling at least etc).

I am not sure, this is your case, but if you have case with modifications of `items` then you should use [TrackByFunction](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction). This will prevent rerender of options which are already renderered. Like you add new object to your array and it has some unique key, you can use trackby function, where you specify the key. When Angular will re-render the view, it would not re-rendered already rendered not changed items.